# Auto Scrollable Text View in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, horizontalscrollview

I have been searching on this for awhile. I have textView and it is Scrollable. The issue is it doesn't scroll while text is added. I have listed all my code and photos for an example. What I am needing is the textView to auto scroll when text is typed. This will be horizontal since it is a calculator.

I have tried using cursor position, using spannable, and several things I would normally do. However this has me stumped. Maybe i have something added that is conflicting the movement. This is also done in the `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`

Design

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_equation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:text="@string/tv_equation"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="45sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

MainActivity

```
 binding.tvEquation.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
```

[image]

[image]

It seems to that the when the `overScrollMode` is called, it should auto scroll over. Maybe I am missing something?

> android:overScrollMode="always"

So any advice would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView......
   <TextView.......
   </TextView......
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

to this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_equation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:text="@string/tv_equation"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

And add this line in your code.

Kotlin:

```
binding.tv_equation.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
```

Java:

```
EditText tv_equation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tv_equation); 
tv_equation.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: I am not using EditText. I am only using TextView.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a marquee behaviour in your EditText.
However Marquee is a TextView Property and not an edit text one.

Create an edit text and textview and superimpose on on top of the other ,
On the textview click hide the textview and show the edittext.

have a scrollable textview by

```
 <TextView
      android:id = "@+id/text"
      android:textSize = "20dp"
      android:textAlignment = "center"
      android:layout_width = "match_parent"
      android:ellipsize = "marquee"
      android:fadingEdge = "horizontal"
      android:marqueeRepeatLimit = "marquee_forever"
      android:scrollHorizontally = "true"
      android:textColor = "#ff4500"
      android:text = "Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text"
      android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
      android:singleLine = "true" />
```

now create a toggle functionality like

```
text.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
editText.setText(edititemname);
```

That way it will give an illusion that the same text is being scrolled when unselected and scrolls when it loses focus.

PS: add `editText.setSelection(editText.length())` for putting cursor at end

Ps: If you just need a Scrollable text view the code block of the textview is enough

Comment: I was trying to stay away from edit text but if it's easier with edittext I can change it. I was trying to get it to work with textview and using marquee did not work for me on textview

Comment: If you just need the textview. The block of code in XML is enough

Comment: i did what you said and all it did was crashed the app

Comment: i had to just go the traditional route with the edit text.. why is it you cannot use a textView to auto scroll